# Does IoTivity has web UI?

Tags: iot, iotivity

Recently I have gone through the IoTvity framework. Even it has cloud folder for stack, resource, account and message it does not have the web part in it.  It has separate installations with different OS. Is this is not a platform like AWS IoT, BlueMix so that we can see and manage the devices in Web.

Comment: Not sure why you've flagged scons here? It's not related to your question.

Answer (score 1):

It is about to come in the next release (1.3). Please take a look at https://wiki.iotivity.org/1.3_release_plan for more information